# Maven Wildfly remote deploy

Tags: java, maven, deployment, wildfly

Maven deploy error:

ERROR: JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: the server presented no authentication mechanisms

> --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.1.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ API ---
>
> Apr 09, 2014 10:31:42 PM org.xnio.Xnio
>
> INFO: XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
>
> Apr 09, 2014 10:31:42 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio
>
> INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
>
> Apr 09, 2014 10:31:42 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl
>
> **INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final** (I'm use *Wildfly 8.0.0.Final*)
>
> Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm

Maven config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>192.168.57.114</hostname>
        <port>9990</port>
        <name>user</name>
        <password>passwd</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

lsof -i results (from server 192.168.57.114):

```
java      5123       jboss  294u  IPv4  12006      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)
java      5123       jboss  322u  IPv4  12011      0t0  TCP 192.168.57.114:9990 (LISTEN)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Resolve:**

Change

```
 <name>user</name>
```

to

```
 <username>user</username>
```

from maven configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the native Management Interface for your Server? For 8.0.0.Final this Interface is no longer Part of the Standard configuration.

I ran into the same problem since the maven Plugin requires the native interface, I think.

Comment: I use wildfly-maven-plugin and wildfly standalone with default configuration. If I'm not wrong wildfly-maven-plugin use http management interface.

Comment: Are you using 8.0.0.Final or still CR1? With the switch to the final version, the deployment did no longer work for me until I added the native management interface again. Please see this issue:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2937

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. There was a problem with the deployment through the http-interface since I needed to remove the security realm from this interface. In this case the server doesn't provide an authentication mechanism and the deployment fails. As a workaround I enabled the native interface again on port 9999 and used this one for deployment.

Comment: Removing the security realm from the management interfaces is never a good solution, you are then essentially allowing complete unauthenticated access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexey Savchuk is right <username> is the correct config. While deploying remotely you need to make sure that you have Management Realm. And it can be created using add-user.sh/bat script located in your <wildfly installation>/bin. Run through console instructions to add management user.